# Connecting to a PostgresSQL Database Instance on Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've been trying to use the instructions found on [amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.PostgreSQL.html) to set up my PostgreSQL database instance and connected it to PG Commander.  After getting an initial connection error I checked to see if there were any common issues and found that usually security settings are the culprit.  When I went to fix the security settings I got the following message:

> Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region.
>   DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is
>   supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your
>   DB Instances. Go to the EC2 Console, Go to the EC2 Console to view and
>   manage your VPC Security Groups.

I went to the network ACL and Security Group tabs there and changed them to accept all traffic from my IP, but I still haven't been able to connect.  I also tried using `portquiz.net` to check whether the port I'm using is accessible and it is.  Is it possible I'm doing something wrong, or are there other reasons the connection might not be working?

UPDATE:  The same issue occurs with a similarly configured MySQL instance, suggesting that the issue either isn't to do with any particular settings for my PostgresSQL manager or has to do with settings present in both PG Commander / Postgres and Sequel Pro / MySQL.

Comment: If you've established that the port is open, then it may be that PostgreSQL is rejecting the connection. I'm not sure what the default for Postgres is, but for MySQL/MariaDB it doesn't allow connections from outside localhost.

Comment: Do you have a Linux VM in the same VPC you can SSH into externally? To admin my MySQL RDS instance I connect via an SSH port forward from a web machine.

Comment: I'm gonna state the obvious just to get it out there: Make sure you set the `Publicly Accessible` option to `Yes` on your RDS instance (I'm assuming you're trying to connect from your own computer and not from an instance in the same VPC as the RDS instance).

Comment: @Bazze I just checked and it is publicly accessible.

Comment: @Ben Thanks, is there a way to check that?  I'm using postgres.app right now.